# C++ statement analysis

Tags: c++, stl

I am seeing a code where in the program it is creating a hash_map:

```
   // Create a hash_map hm3 with the 
   // allocator of hash_map hm1
   hash_map <MyStr, MyInt>::allocator_type hm1_Alloc;
   hm1_Alloc = hm1.get_allocator( );
   hash_map <MyStr, MyInt, hash_compare <MyStr, less_str > > hm3( hash_compare <MyStr, less_str > (), hm1_Alloc );
   hm3.insert( Int_Pair( "three", 30 ) );
```

Could anyone please explain me the 3rd statement where hm3 is declared.

```
hash_map <MyStr, MyInt, hash_compare <MyStr, less_str > > hm3( hash_compare <MyStr, less_str > (), hm1_Alloc );
```

The complete program can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zz3703d(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hash_map <MyStr, MyInt, hash_compare <MyStr, less_str > >
```

This is a type, being a hash map which maps a MyStr to a MyInt, using a [custom hash compare functor type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s1byw77%28VS.80%29.aspx). Let's call it `HashMap`.

```
hash_compare <MyStr, less_str > ()
```

The syntax `T()` creates a temporary object of type `T` using the default constructor. The code above constructs the hash compare functor. Let's call this object `hashCmp`.

```
hm1_Alloc
```

This is a custom allocator.

That declaration can then be rewritten as

```
typedef hash_compare<MyStr, less_str>     HashCmpT;
typedef hash_map<MyStr, MyInt, HashCmpT>  HashMap;

HashCmpT hashCmp;

HashMap hm3 (hashCmp, hm1_Alloc);
```

Comment: ... `(HashCmp(), hm` .. probably?

Comment: Hm. It dependes on what `hash_compare` is. If it's a template function - we should have (). But if that's really produces functor, you are write. I haven't read MSDN article, so I guessed what `hash_compare` could be, so I suppose you re write.

Comment: I have never seen such `hash_compare <MyStr, less_str > ()` creation of object.

Comment: @MInner: using `T()` to create an object of T with the default constructor is pretty common in STL, [e.g. `std::sort(l.begin(), l.end(), std::greater<int>() );`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/greater.html).

Comment: @KennyTM: Is it same as `new T()`? Or it works only with functors?

Comment: @MInner: No it's not. `T()` creates a temporary object of type `T` on the stack. `new T()` allocates a pointer of type `T*` on the heap. The syntax `T()` works with any types with a default constructor, e.g. `int()`.

Comment: @KennyTM: Shouldn't you be passing an instance of `HashCmp` using `HashCmp()` as hm3 constructor parameter?

Answer (score 0):

We create object called hm3. It's class is  hash_map `<MyStr, MyInt, hash_compare <MyStr, less_str > >`. It (class) is a template class hash_map and this template takes two parameters - two class names. First one is MyStr. Second one is template function `hash_compare <MyStr, less_str >`. This (second) template takes also two parametrs. They are `MyStr` class and something called `less_str`.

Why such template? I suppose first parametr of hash is the container of element. The second one is the function for comparison such containers.

Add:
And about constructor: it takes result of template function `smt hash_compare <MyStr, less_str > (void)` and some kind of object.

Add2:
It can be shown like this:

```
typedef hash_map <MyStr, MyInt, hash_compare <MyStr, less_str > > Someclass;
Someotherclass var = hash_compare <MyStr,    less_str > (); // `var` is what this function returned

Someclass hm3( var, hm1_Alloc );
```

Comment: this part is easy to understand but what about the latter part `hm3( hash_compare <MyStr, less_str > (), hm1_Alloc )`

Comment: It's constructor parametrs. `hash_compare <MyStr, less_str > ()` is a template function with two template parameters and zero function parameters, and it returns something. That's what it returns is first parameter of constructor. See my answer edit for more.

Answer (score 0):

It is creating an object of `hash_map` named `hm3`. Here is my take on the parameters:

Template parameter 1 (MyStr): Key for the map

Template parameter 2 (MyInt): Value for the key

Template parameter 3 : The comparison function to compare two keys. You are using a function called `hash_compare` (which again is a template) to do this.

The constructor you are using (2nd one in the MSDN) of the `hash_map` class requires an *instance* of the comparator function and the allocator. You are creating an unnamed (temporary) instance of the function object `hash_compare` and passing an allocator `hm1_Alloc` to the constructor.